Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext') while using monorepo setup using lerna
I am using Lerna to setup a monorepo, when I import the package into another application I am getting below errors.
react.development.js:210 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
   react.development.js:1619 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
   at Object.useContext (react.development.js:1619:21)
   at useTheme (useThemeWithoutDefault.js:16:59)
   at useTheme (useTheme.js:14:77)
   at Box (createBox.js:37:72)
   at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:15486:18)
   at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19240:20)
   at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21670:16)
   at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)

**Below is the @dummy/login/lib/login.tsx -**

import \* as React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';

const Item = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) =\> ({
backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#1A2027' : '#fff',
...theme.typography.body2,
padding: theme.spacing(1),
textAlign: 'center',
color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
}));

export default function Login() {
return (
<Box\>
<p>I am inside FE code.</p>

);
}

**Below is the Application code where I am trying to import login.tsx :-**

import Login from "@dummy/login";
import React from "react";
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

const LoginComponent:any = () =\> {

return (

<Box\>
<Login\></Login\>
</Box\>

)

}
export default LoginComponent;

Please help me fix the issue.
I am expecting the output to display as "I am inside FE code."
The above code works fine if I remove the styled components and if I dont use any react hooks.
